# Is it possible to programmatically group shapes into a collection for bulk transformation?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm drawing a map on the screen according to a config file that's been read, so (as far as I know... but I've only been working in WPF for two days) all the map's shapes in the canvas need to be drawn and transformed programmatically.  One of the objects to be drawn is (for any intents and purposes) a grid.  Depending on the current zoom factor, I need to scale the shapes to be larger or smaller.  I'm looking for something that has the same effect as the following (fake) code:

```
ShapeGroup g = new ShapeGroup();
g.add(rect);
g.add(line1);
g.add(line2);
g.add(line3);

g.transform(new ScaleTransform(2.0));
```

Does WPF have any similar *programmatic* functionality?  Thanks!

Comment: Check this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2007/10/05/ui-scaling-ui-zooming-with-wpf.aspx) by Ivo Manolov.  I think it answers your question.

Comment: Wow, that's better than I hoped for!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use any container control (Grid, DockPanel, StackPanel, etc) to group those shapes, then apply transformation to the container. The same idea demonstrated in the article suggested by @wdosanjos in comment above. In that article the author picked DockPanel as container for transformation. For illustration, the code will be about like :

```
Grid g = new Grid();
g.Children.add(rect);
g.Children.add(line1);
g.Children.add(line2);
g.Children.add(line3);

g.LayoutTransform(new ScaleTransform(2.0));
```

Note: The code didn't demonstrate positioning shapes inside the container.